# Which flex microarchitecture I should choose?

Tags: apache-flex

I am planing to introduce flex microarchitecture in one of my flex application. There are many flex microarchitectures available, such as Cairngorm, Pure MVC, Mate, Parsley, Swiz, Spring ActionScript. Being new to flex, I need to know which one I should pick, I mean which one will good for me in terms of

1. Complexity
2. Flexibility
3. Open source / closed
4. Learning curve

Comment: The choice doesn't matter; and choosing a framework is incredibly subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Like Flextras said, we can't really pick for you since we don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  However, with that said, don't use Cairngorm (unless it's version 3, and you still need Parsley since they're just extensions).

Personally, my choice has either been Parsley or RobotLegs.  Parsley is good for large, complex projects because of the flexibility it provides.  Robotlegs is better for small to medium projects because it's simple to use and small in size.